# Unable to create a manifest resource name for ______ in VB

Tags: vb.net, resx

I am experiencing issues regarding a specific class in my VB2010 code being able to generate a corresponding .resx. The error I'm getting is as below:

```
Unable to create a manifest resource name for "My Project\CTSelector.resx". 
Could not find file 'Z:\Physicists\Ernest\RT Shielding VB Code - 
v2\RTShieldingTestCode\RTShieldingTestCode\My Project\CTSelector.vb'
```

Comment: Right-click the .resx file, select "run custom tool", clean, rebuild. Fixed?

Comment: I'm fairly new to vb, where can I locate the .resx file/

Comment: You'll find it and everything in your solution in Visual Studio's *solution explorer* toolwindow.